# Array of sets in CPLEX OPL

Tags: arrays, set, cplex, opl

I am trying to implement an array of sets in CPLEX.

The end result should look like this:

```
{int} Z[1..6] = [{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4},{2,3,4},{2,3,4},{2,3,4}]
```

Each array element is derrived from two other arrays.

```
int X[1..6] = [1,1,1,2,2,2]
int Y[1..6] = [5,5,5,4,4,4]
```

So each element of Z represents a range of ints between the elemets of arrays X and Y

I tried to do it with following code:

```
range A = 1..6;
execute calculateZ{
  for(var i in A){
    for(v = X[i]; v <= Y[i]; v++){
      Opl.item(W[i],v-1) = v;
    }
  }
}
```

My questions are:

- -is an array of sets possible at all?
- -if so how can I fill the elements of my set? opl.item doesnt seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use OPL scripting but I d rather rely on OPL modeling part:

```
int X[1..6] = [1,1,1,2,2,2];
int Y[1..6] = [5,5,5,4,4,4];

{int} Z[i in 1..6] = asSet(X[i]..Y[i]);

execute
{
writeln(Z);
}
```

gives

```
[{1 2 3 4 5} {1 2 3 4 5} {1 2 3 4 5} {2 3 4} {2 3 4} {2 3 4}]
```

PS:

later on you asked how to do that in scripting.

```
range r=1..6;

int X[r] = [1,1,1,2,2,2];
int Y[r] = [5,5,5,4,4,4];

{int} Z[i in r] = asSet(X[i]..Y[i]);
{int} Z2[i in r];

execute
{
for(var i in r) for(var j=X[i];j<=Y[i];j++) Z2[i].add(j);  

writeln(Z);
writeln(Z2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

just out of curiosity, what would I have to change in my execute script in order to get it right?